# Gini index different expressions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, order-statistics

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable with positive finite expectation.
The Lorenzcurve $L_X$ is defined by
$$ L_X(u) = \frac{\int_0^u F_X^{-1}(y) dy}{E(X)}, \quad 0 \leq u \leq 1,$$
where
$$
F_X^{-1}(y) = \begin{cases}
\sup\{x : F_X(x) \leq y\}, \quad 0 \leq y < 1 \\
\sup\{x : F_X(x) \leq y\}, \quad y = 1
\end{cases}
$$
is the right continuous inverse distribution function of the random variable X.
The Gini-Index $G$ is defined by $G = 1 - 2\int_0^1 L_X(u) du$.

I've stepped across the following equation
$$ G = \frac{E(X_{2:2}) - E( X_{1:2} )}{E(X_{2:2}) + E(X_{1:2})}, $$
where $X_{1:2} < X_{2:2}$ are the order statistics of a random sample of size 2 drawn from X.

Is this a true statement for any random variable X? If so, why?

In addition, I have calculated the Gini-Index in the case of $X \sim \exp(\lambda)$ for both expressions above and came to the same result, but I do fail to see any justification for the general case.

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that
$$
\max(x,y)+\min(x,y)=x+y,
$$
and
$$
\max(x,y)-\min(x,y)=|x-y|=(x+y)-2\min(x,y).
$$
Then, if $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. with cdf $F$,
\begin{align}
&\frac{\mathsf{E}\max(X,Y)-\mathsf{E}\min(X,Y)}{\mathsf{E}\max(X,Y)+\mathsf{E}\min(X,Y)}=1-\frac{\mathsf{E}\min(X,Y)}{\mathsf{E}X}\\
&\qquad=1-\frac{1}{\mathsf{E}X}\int_0^\infty[1-F(x)]^2\,dx.
\end{align}
It remains to show that the RHS equals the first definition.